# The 'Lo' in "Lo faccio subito."

Tags: pronouns

I am a beginner in Italian language and I am wondering about the 'Lo' in different sentences, like "Lo faccio subito.". What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Greg!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the equivalent for "I do **it** immediately" or "I do **that** immediately"; in the same way *lo vedo* is the equivalent for "I see it" or "I see that."

Answer (score 3):

The word *lo* can be either an article or a pronoun. You can distinguish between the two cases by looking at what follows: if it's a noun (or a pair adjective-noun), then *lo* is an article; otherwise it's most likely a pronoun.

In this case the next word is *faccio*, which is a verb and the role is of pronoun. The meaning is “I'll do it at once” where *it* corresponds to *lo*. The tense is different: present in Italian, future in English; but it's just how the two languages work. Also in Italian one can say *lo farò subito*, with essentially the same meaning; using the present gives the idea that the thing will be done really immediately (like in *I'm already at it*).

There is another big difference: the article *lo* can be used only before vowels (with elision), *z*, *s+consonant*, *gn*, *x*, *ps* and *pn* (in this case, many people use *il*, though); otherwise the article should be *il*.

The pronoun *lo* is used before *any* word: it has no alternative form (for masculine singular, of course). The feminine singular form is *la*, the plural is *li*.

Answer (score 2):

It is also the equivalent of "I'll do it at once" (the use of future for a decision with immediate effect). For a beginner, I think it would be better to 
remember that "that" in Italian is normally "quello" or "quella" (and also "che"). "Lo" and "la" should really be the equivalent of "it" or "him" or "her". 
Of course one could say "I'll do that at once" instead of "I'll do it at once", but that's another story.